# Open and closed parshiot

Tags: safrus, writing-printing

In the Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh Deah, Laws of Sefer Torah, [סימן רעה הלכה ב](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.275.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)  it  relates to the issue of between paragraph spacing. I would to know the frequency of open and closed *parshiot* (paragraphs) in a Torah scroll?

Answer (score 1):

Rambam (Sefer Torah 8:10) counts 290 open sections and 379 closed sections in the Torah for a total of 669. His lists are used in virtually all Torah scrolls today.

Comment: We could add to this I guess 4 sections between the books which are a sort of "parsha" break I guess

Answer (score 0):

There are 291 pesuchos and 382 sesumos. See [here](https://www.xn----2hcm6cgyhbh.com/2010/06/torah-stats.html)

Comment: I have to guess his 4 extra sections are for between the books, but it's unclear how exactly he's counting. Comments there have noted other mistakes in his lists.

Comment: Link repaired. 15 characters